When someone eats a second DF, they die. If Brooke cannot die unless his bones are destroyed, wouldn't that mean he could still eat another?
Brooke ate the Revive Revive fruit. Because of the way his body is after finding it again, in the sense he can’t be killed unless his bones are destroyed, should he not be physically capable of eating a second DF without it killing him?
Since we haven’t seen how that kills people, (insides shut down? Heart attack?) I feel like it’s reasonable to assume it’s possible. I’d love to tweak this theory again when I learn why BB was able to eat more than one, beyond the multiple souls theory.

Does this answer your question? What will happen if one person eats two Devil Fruits?

It is true that a person dying by eating multiple devil fruits has never been shown (ironically, we've only been shown a person eating more than one devil fruit and surviving), but the effects of eating a second devil fruit have been described in chapter 385: the body would shatter in pieces so little that no trace of the person is left. It is safe to assume that this would be fatal to Brook. See also this answer addressing the fundamental issue.

If eating another devil fruit causes you to shatter into nothingness, that would include Brook's bones, and thus, he would die. It's not a loophole for him, rather it's just a bit harder to kill him by regular means.
